# How to set up TortoiseHG with Fiddler2 as proxy server?

Tags: fiddler, tortoisehg

I want to watch TortoiseHG's web requests to a Mercurial server, but I can't seem to configure it correctly so that I can see the activity from Fiddler. Here's what I've done:

Start Fiddler
TortoiseHg -> Global Settings -> Proxy
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888 (I confirmed within Fiddler that this is correct)

TortoiseHg -> Synchronize
Pull, preview incoming changes

Nothing shows up in Fiddler. Shouldn't I be seeing the requests and responses?

I'm running Windows 7 if that's any help.